# Webview doesn't show some images in Kotlin

Tags: html, kotlin, android-webview

I made a app with webview but when i opened a website logo doesn't appeared. I tried this with real devices also but it's same. Also page perfectly opening in android's web browser.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, Have you tried debugging your WebView to see if there are any errors while loading the website?

Comment: @Seanvd yes i tried but there is nothing. I was made code like this.
https://github.com/tensor-programming/Kotlin_WebView